# Are the ffmpeg libraries able to suggest the audio codec?

Tags: audio, conversion, codec

I want to write a small audio data converter for a very special goal. I'd like to use different audio formats as input without investigating the input by myself and before selecting codec.

Is there a call within the ffmpeg libraries that can tell me which CODEC to use based on the input audio file?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: It would have to be a very esoteric goal for this to not just be reinventing the wheel. On Mac there's XLD or Max. I'm sure there must be a myriad others for different platforms.